# Jquery Sortable: clone + appendTo more than one possible target

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am making a planner where on the side you have a list of tasks that are split into 3 categories. Any item from this list needs to be able to be cloned and appended to one or more of the 7 days of the week.

So dragging it to any day, would need to clone it and show it on the day it was dragged to. So far I haven't found a way to indicate that the item can be appendedTo sort4 through sort10. Is there a way to figure out what the target is you're hovering over to fill in the appendTo() with a variable?

My current code only allows an item to be cloned to one column out of 7.

My code:

```
Function sortable(){

        // the 3 categories of which each item needs to be cloned

        $( "#sort1, #sort2, #sort3" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            remove: function(event, ui) {
                ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sort4');
                $(this).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }).disableSelection();


        // on each day, you can drag and drop to any other 
           day which needs to move the task

        $( "#sort4, #sort5, #sort6, #sort7, #sort8, #sort9, #sort10" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    };
```

I did manage to find a bit of a solution to my problem which works, but I'm not sure it's the most efficient way. Based on the cursor position, I can decide the selector and that allows it to be sorted the way I need it to.

```
    function sortable() {
        $("#sort1, #sort2, #sort3").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            remove: function (event, ui) {
                let pos;
                let scroll = document.querySelector('.week_planner--container').scrollLeft;
                let cursor = (event.pageX - $('.week_planner--container').offset().left) + scroll;
                if (cursor >= 0 && cursor <= 170) {
                    pos = '#sort4';
                } else if (cursor >= 171 && cursor <= 340) {
                    pos = '#sort5';
                } else if (cursor >= 341 && cursor <= 510) {
                    pos = '#sort6';
                } else if (cursor >= 511 && cursor <= 680) {
                    pos = '#sort7';
                } else if (cursor >= 681 && cursor <= 850) {
                    pos = '#sort8';
                } else if (cursor >= 851 && cursor <= 1020) {
                    pos = '#sort9';
                } else if (cursor >= 1021 && cursor <= 1190) {
                    pos = '#sort10';
                }

                ui.item.clone().appendTo(pos);
                $(this).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }).disableSelection();

        $("#sort4, #sort5, #sort6, #sort7, #sort8, #sort9, #sort10").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    };
```

Comment: Please provide your html, or preferably a demo that shows your issue.

Comment: I have recorded a video: https://vimeo.com/352944347

Comment: What I want is to be able to copy the same task in any of the weekdays. But the appendTo("#sort4") only allows it to be sorted into "Maandag" because that has the id=sort4.

Comment: OK. The demo is useful, but we would prefer to see a working code sample here, within your question. Also, using the cursor measurement system is not a good idea. What if you change the font size or layout?

Comment: I have forked the fiddle I have based myself on here: http://jsfiddle.net/unahc9jf/4/

Comment: So you have 3 columns of items on the list. From the first list you can clone items to the second list. But I want to be able to drag it to any list I want and clone it to that one.

So it needs to be able to clone into list 2 AND list 3 if I want to. Right now it's only possible to clone to list 2.

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/h0nLd2ro/. This is closer to what you want I think. Next, please tell me what you now need.

Comment: That's just the normal sorting. Some items are big so you sometimes need to work on them more than once. So they still need to stay on the left side in the first column, but also be copied to another one. So let's say we have Task 1 in column 1 (which is a list of tasks). I want to work on Task 1 on Monday AND Tuesday (which are column 2 and 3. So I want to copy Task 1 to those 2 days and have them stay there. But Task 1 won't be completely done yet so I might need to be able to plan it on Wednesday too. So a version has to stay in column 1 until mark Task 1 as complete.

Comment: Closer? http://jsfiddle.net/fjt4rL7p/1/

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you so much!! :D

Comment: If you post the link as an answer, I will mark it as helpful :) Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. I have posted this as an answer. Let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's sortable offers a few events that you can tap into for this. I stored which list we're dragging from and its position so that we can determine whether we should clone after dragging, or not.

```js
$(function() 
{
  var $movingFrom = null;
  var index = null;
  $(".connectedSortable").sortable(
  {
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    start: function(event, ui) 
    {
      // Log which list we're dragging from and where in the list the item currently resides.
      $movingFrom = ui.item.parent();
      index = ui.item.index();
    },
    receive: function(event, ui) // This is called when we finish the drag and things have moved.
    {
      if (event.target.id == "sortable1")
      {
        // Prevent 1st list receiving items from elsewhere
        ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
      }
      else 
      {
        if ($movingFrom.attr("id") == "sortable1") 
        {
          // If we're moving from the 1st list...
          
          var $insertBefore = $("#sortable1 li").get(index);
          if ($insertBefore !== undefined)
          {
            // Clone original 1st list item
            ui.item.clone().insertBefore($insertBefore);
          }
          else
          {
            // Must have come from the end of the list...
            $("#sortable1").append(ui.item.clone());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2,
#sortable3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left; 
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li,
#sortable3 li 
{
  font-family:Calibri;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color:white;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="///cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="///cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="demo">
  <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to make sure that the `ul` has some width when it has no `li`s inside.